# How to know item selected on spinner?

Tags: android, switch-statement

I have the following code:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, "You selected " +item.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    Toast.makeText(this, "You didn't select any preset", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

And the following array:

```
    <string-array name="presets_array">
    <item>Light Car</item>
    <item>Medium Car</item>
    <item>Heavy Car</item>
    <item>Van</item>
    </string-array>
```

It's working fine, when I select Light car it displays the correct text and so on with the others.
But I want to do more things, if selected thing is Van, change weight value, if medium car, other cost, etc.

I think I have to use a switch but I'm not sure how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some options. You should choose the best which fits to you...

**Just checking position**

Good performance but if you change array order, you must re-order the switch statement

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    Toast.makeText(this, "You selected " + item.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    swith(position) {
        case 0:
            // CODE for Light Car
            break;
        case 1:
            // CODE for Medium Car
            break;
        case 2:
            // CODE for Heavy Car
            break;
        case 3:
            // CODE for Van
            break;
    }
}
```

**String Checking**

Low performance since you have to compare Strings several times in the worst case.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

    Toast.makeText(this, "You selected " + item.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if(item.toString().equals("Light Car")) {
        // CODE
    } else if(item.toString().equals("Medium Car")) {
        // CODE
    } else if(item.toString().equals("Heavy Car")) {
        // CODE
    } else if(item.toString().equals("Van")) {
        // CODE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write code similar to this code inside onItemSelected method:

```
switch (item)
```

{
   case Light Car:
   // TODD
    break;

case Van:
  // TODO
  break;
.......

}

Comment: But what do I exactly put after each case? Light Car, Van... are not recognized. I can put R.array.presets_array but not each string, they don't appear under R.string.

Comment: I understood from your question that you want to do different things with different selected items from the spinner, could you tell me what you want to do with each selected item, and if you could give me a screen shot of your layout from the app. and the xaml code.